# Greenplum - how do I use SERIAL column and generate in the order of the data inserted

Tags: sequence, greenplum

When trying to insert multiple records from an ordered query into a Greenplum table which includes a SERIAL column, the generated values are not in the order of the selected data.

If, however, the `generate_series` function is used, the serial column is generated correctly.

I'm sure this has to do with each segment inserting records, but surely if the order is specified in the source query, it should honour that and generate values accordingly.

How can I get the generated serial values to match the order of the insert query?

My workaround would be to use row_number() over the order by columns to generate a value to insert directly, but I was hoping that I could use SERIAL and not have to work around it.

A basic example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ord_test1, ord_test2;

CREATE TABLE ord_test1(
col1 serial,
series1 int
) DISTRIBUTED RANDOMLY;

CREATE TABLE ord_test2(
col1 serial,
test1_series1 int
) DISTRIBUTED RANDOMLY;


-- generates serial in order of generate_series
INSERT INTO ord_test1 (series1)
SELECT g from generate_series(1,100) g; 

-- generates serial in random order
INSERT INTO ord_test2 (test1_series1)
SELECT series1 from ord_test1 order by series1;

SELECT * from ord_test1 order by series1;
SELECT * from ord_test2 order by test1_series1;
```